# How to project a face to another face?

Tags: python

I am doing arch. work and I need to project the top face of wall to the bottom face of the ceiling for further modification (like Revit). But, these two faces are in two different objects. Is there any python code can do it?
[image: Step 1: I use knife projection cut the top face of wall]

[[image: Step 2: I would like to use python to project the cut faces to ceiling [2]]

[image: Step 3: That's the final product I wanted]

I have try shrinkwrap modifier, but it seems that it cannot do well at drop edge of the ceiling.

[image]

Also, Boolean modifier is not good because it is unstable. If the dropline of the ceiling is overlapped with the wall, the modifier will be crashed.

See my second example:
[image]

Comment: Hi. Do you really need it to be in Python?

Comment: If you can do it in same way, I may accept. But...It seems that the shrinkwrap modifier cannot do well....

Comment: I can't imagine something in Python that could be better or more accurate than shrinkwrap. But could you upload your blend file to test it? Please use this link to do it then past the result link in your question: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thx, I uploaded

Comment: ok. That's what I wanted to do with shrinkwrap. But how to expect something else with a script if each mesh subdisions are not in correspondance?

Comment: My idea is that:  Using Edge Split to the top faces of wall, so I can manipulate each face independently. Then I need a python script to relocate each top face of wall to the location of the ceiling along the z-axis. If I can do it, I had a script to do the next step.

Comment: A boolean? If walls are by default tall enough and ceilings solidified? second edit of this comment: yes it can work.

Comment: no, blender boolean is not good if there is any overlapping. In arch model, the wall usually align with beam under ceiling. So, it happens very often. See:https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=sV7YeDSV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extrude *from*  a cut in the ceiling rather than trying to project the wall to it.

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicate off the top surface of your wall, and make a clean profile of it using <kbd>X</kbd> limited dissolve, but not so harshly as to damage the curvature.

[image]

- From orthographic Z, *Header Menu > Mesh > Knife Project* the profile
  onto the ceiling, checking '*Cut Through*'

[image]

- With Snap set to *Vertex* and *Active*, and a convenient vertex active, <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> Extrude a duplicate of the resulting selection in the ceiling downwards in 2 stages, snapping on the way.. (Take care not to create internal faces)

[image]

- <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> scale the bottom of the wall to 0 about its median, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > *By Distance* merge out redundant vertices.. You can tidy up again with Limited Dissolve.)